# The largevalue on fipy internal boundary condition

Tags: python, fipy

I have tried internal boundary condition in code below.

I found that while I have not set an external boundary condition, the solved result will depend on the LargeValue. Besides, while I increase the largeValue, I must redefine the equation again, otherwise the equation couldn't be changed by just setting a new value to LargeValue.

I have used the `sweep` method to try to get a better result, but it does not work.

Below is my code. Is there any mistake? Hope someone will help me!

```
for step in range(steps):
    equation2=DiffusionTerm(coeff=perittivity)==ImplicitSourceTerm(largeValue*mask)-largeValue*mask*value
    potential.setValue(0)
    k=0.5
    residual=1
    while residual>1e-10 and abs(k-residual)>1e-18 :
        k=residual
        residual=equation2.sweep(potential)
        if __name__=="__main__":
            viewer.plot()
        print step,residual,k-residual#,equation2,largeValue
    largeValue=Variable(value = largeValue.value*1.1)
```

Comment: It's not currently possible to run the code sample as a number of variables are not defined. Consider posting the entire code sample to make it easier for others to rerun the code and help to debug. Also, consider explaining how things are not working. Is there an error or does the result look wrong?